# German iTunes Store: No Bank / Paypal?

Tags: itunes-store

I'm a long time customer of the German iTunes store (recently only iTunes match). My VISA was not valid anymore, so I had to change. Not having a VISA atm, I wanted to go for Paypal or direct bank transactions.... however, I could see neither of them on my screen..

This despite internet research showing both apparently are supported for the German store - how can I salvage this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The itunes stores payment option for your country is the one you see there when editing your payment option.

You also can select none for the moment and get an iTunes Gift Card

Comment: A German iTunes Gift Card.  Most iTunes gift cards on the internet are for the US store, they won't work with a non-US account.